# Google Analytics - Custom Dimension - Internal Traffic - Only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using new google universal analytics on my website. To exclude internal (my own) traffic on my site from reports I have created a user scope custom dimension in GA which I use to filter dataviews.

I have created a secret page including this code to set the CD myself with the all browsers I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var dimensionValue = 'INTERNAL_TRAFFIC';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue );
 </script>
```

I have visited this hidden site with all devices and browsers that I use. But it only works with Chrome (desktop and iOS). All requests on my page with google are allocated to that CD.

ALL other browsers don't, I only ever see my chrome access on my dataview filtered to include only traffic from that CD.

Any idea why this might be? Do I have to do it differently for the other browsers?

Thanks for any help,
Phil

Comment: I think problem might be somewhere else. Are you sure that custom dimmension is set before pageview? Double check filters in GA views. Do you set up dimension1 as hit, session or user scope?

Comment: Yes that might have been the problem. I had the JS added in a wordpress page, which seemed to work in Chrome but not the others. I have now created a simple html page independen't from wordpress, now it seems to work with all browsers!

Thanks!